# Modificar Excel con python

Tags: python

Hice un script para cambiar un carácter de toda una fila de Excel por otro con Python, ejemplo todas las casillas de una fila del Excel tiene texto así: 'nombre_de_cuenta' y yo lo que hice fue cambiar el guion bajo por un espacio en blanco = 'nombre de cuenta' pero solo lo puedo hacer el cambio desde la A a la Z ya que para indicar el rango en el que se hace el cambio use el código ASCII, alguien sabe como puedo ir mas allá es decir de la A a la AZ.

```
import openpyxl

path = "archivo.xlsx"

plantilla = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheetnames = plantilla.sheetnames

ws = plantilla[sheetnames[0]]

# Este es el rango en el que el cambio se realiza la 65=A es el inicio y 
#el 90=Z es el  final           
for i in range (65,90):
aux = ws[chr(i)+str(1)].value

ws[chr(i)+str(1)] = aux.replace(chr(95),' ')

plantilla.save(path)

print('bien')
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa [openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_interval](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_interval). Esta función devuelve, dados una columna inicial y final, todas las columnas intermedias (inclusive).

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_interval

path = "archivo.xlsx"

plantilla = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheetnames = plantilla.sheetnames

ws = plantilla[sheetnames[0]]

for i in get_column_interval("A", "AZ"):
    print(i)
    aux = str(ws[i+"1"].value)
    ws[i+"1"] = aux.replace(chr(95),' ')

plantilla.save(path)
```